# What is XlaBuilder for?

Tags: c++, tensorflow, tensorflow-xla

What's the XLA class `XlaBuilder` for? [The docs](https://www.tensorflow.org/xla/operation_semantics) describe its interface but don't provide a motivation.

The presentation in the docs, and indeed the comment above `XlaBuilder` in the source code

```
// A convenient interface for building up computations.
```

suggests it's no more than a utility. However, this doesn't appear to explain its behaviour in other places. For example, we can construct an `XlaOp` with an `XlaBuilder` via e.g.

```
XlaOp ConstantLiteral(XlaBuilder* builder, const LiteralSlice& literal);
```

Here, it's not clear to me what role `builder` plays (note functions for constructing `XlaOp`s aren't documented on the published docs). Further, when I add two `XlaOp`s (with `+` or `Add`) it appears the ops must be constructed with the same builder, else I see

```
F tensorflow/core/platform/statusor.cc:33] Attempting to fetch value instead of handling error Invalid argument: No XlaOp with handle -1
```

Indeed, `XlaOp` retains a handle for an `XlaBuilder`. This suggests to me that the `XlaBuilder` has a more fundamental significance.

Beyond the title question, is there a use case for using multiple `XlaBuilder`s, or would you typically use one global instance for everything?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`XlaBuilder` is the C++ API for building up XLA computations -- conceptually this is like building up a function, full of various operations, that you could execute over and over again on different input data.

Some background, XLA serves as an abstraction layer for creating executable blobs that run on various target accelerators (CPU, GPU, TPU, IPU, ...), conceptually kind of an "accelerator virtual machine" with conceptual similarities to earlier systems like [PeakStream](https://web.stanford.edu/class/ee380/Abstracts/070926-PeakStream.pdf) or the line of work that led to [ArBB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intel_Array_Building_Blocks).

The `XlaBuilder` is a way to enqueue operations into a "computation" (similar to a function) that you want to run against the various set of accelerators that XLA can target. The operations at this level are often referred to as "High Level Operations" (HLOs).

The returned `XlaOp` represents the result of the operation you've just enqueued. (Aside/nerdery: this is a classic technique used in "builder" APIs that represent the program in "Static Single Assignment" form under the hood, the *operation* itself and the *result* of the operation can be unified as one concept!)

XLA computations are very similar to functions, so you can think of what you're doing with an `XlaBuilder` like building up a function. (Aside: they're *called* "computations" because they do a little bit more than a straightforward function -- conceptually they are coroutines that can talk to an external "host" world and also talk to each other via networking facilities.)

So the fact `XlaOp`s can't be used across `XlaBuilder`s may make more sense with that context -- in the same way that when building up a function you can't grab intermediate results in the internals of other functions, you have to compose them with function calls / parameters. In `XlaBuilder` you can [`Call`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/a8b6a7c9c5efdf962d19d0d1ac8adf2ae9f2b5da/tensorflow/compiler/xla/client/xla_builder.h#L2067) another built computation, which is a reason you might use multiple builders.

As you note, you can *choose to* inline everything into one "mega builder", but often programs are structured as functions that get composed together, and ultimately get called from a few different "entry points". XLA currently aggressively specializes for the entry points it sees API users using, but this is a design artifact similar to inlining decisions, XLA can conceptually reuse computations built up / invoked from multiple callers if it thought that was the right thing to do. Usually it's most natural to enqueue things into XLA however is convenient for your description from the "outside world", and allow XLA to inline and aggressively specialize the "entry point" computations you've built up as you execute them, in Just-in-Time compilation fashion.

Comment: thanks cdleary. So an `XlaBuilder` is like the programmer writing a function, each `XlaOp` represents either the intermediate values in the function or the return value of the function, and the computation (presumably `XlaComputation`) is the actual final function itself? And you can only compose computations not `XlaBuilder`s?